# how to fix exo player crashing?

Tags: android

am trying to create video player app, i use exoplayer but crashs after i start activity

below are errors i got when activity is started

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.smschecker, PID: 9425
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.smschecker/com.example.smschecker.MovieDetails}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2865)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6719)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:449)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error inflating class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
at com.example.smschecker.MovieDetails.onCreate(MovieDetails.java:46)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7015)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7006)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1217)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6719)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:449)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #143 bootstrap method
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView.(PlayerControlView.java:420)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView.(PlayerView.java:493)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView.(PlayerView.java:335)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
at com.example.smschecker.MovieDetails.onCreate(MovieDetails.java:46) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7015) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7006) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1217) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6719) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:449) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Invalid descriptor: VLIII.
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView.(PlayerControlView.java:420) 
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView.(PlayerView.java:493) 
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView.(PlayerView.java:335) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
at com.example.smschecker.MovieDetails.onCreate(MovieDetails.java:46) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7015) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7006) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1217) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6719) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:449) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Comment: Can you post your XML please?

Comment: <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"/>
</LinearLayout>